# javascript, wait for something to be true then run action

Tags: javascript

Well the title kindof says what I need. Because in Javascript timeouts asynchronous I need to know when something becomes true. I don't want busyloop.

Came up with:

```
function do_when(predicate, action, timeout_step) {
    if (predicate()) {
        action();
    } else {
        setTimeout(do_when, timeout_step, predicate, action, timeout_step);
    }
}
```

Is it good Javascript or can I make better?

Comment: @predicate is function, action is also function

Comment: The predicate is the condition when that has to be true before the action is called. **==>** Looks sound to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's decent enough, if it's easy enough to read and it works just fine then it's generally good javascript.

Performance-wise, it's generally better to call the function whenever whatever is set to true happens.  So in whatever function that executes to make `predicate()` return true, you could just call `action()` at the end.  But I'm sure that's what you would have done if you could, right?

You could also look at using a callback, where you register a javascript function to a particular variable or function argument and when the function is run it executes whatever function was set to the callback variable.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what the predicate is, you might be able to fit your problem into an implementation of the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). A while back I wrote a blog post about [creating JavaScript objects with observable properties](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/sean_devlin/archive/2009/08/21/creating-objects-with-observable-properties-in-javascript.aspx). It really depends on what the predicate *is*, but this might get you most of the way there with code like this:

```
var observable = createObservable({ propToWatch: false });
observable.observe('propToWatch', function (oldValue, newValue) { 
    alert('propToWatch has changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue); 
});
observable.propToWatch(true); // alert pops
```

Of course, this might be overkill for your example. Since it's never listed out explicitly (n.b. I am not a very good blogger), here's the complete code needed to make this work:

```
var createMediator = function () {
    var events = {};
    return {
        subscribe: function (eventName, callback) {
            events[eventName] = events[eventName] || [];
            events[eventName].push(callback);
        },
        publish: function (eventName) {
            var i, callbacks = events[eventName], args;
            if (callbacks) {
                args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                for (i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
                    callbacks[i].apply(null, args);
                }
            }
        }
    };
};

var createObservable = function (properties) {
    var notifier = createMediator(), createObservableProperty, observable;
    createObservableProperty = function (propName, value) {
        return function (newValue) {
            var oldValue;
            if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined' &&
                value !== newValue) {
                oldValue = value;
                value = newValue;
                notifier.publish(propName, oldValue, value);
            }
            return value;
        };
    };
    observable = {
        register: function (propName, value) {
            this[propName] = createObservableProperty(propName, value);
            this.observableProperties.push(propName);
        },
        observe: function (propName, observer) {
            notifier.subscribe(propName, observer);
        },
        observableProperties: []
    };
    for (propName in properties) {
        observable.register(propName, properties[propName]);
    }
    return observable;
};
```

My observable objects make use internally of a small eventing framework (the createMediator function) I wrote once for a project. (*Before* realizing jQuery supported custom events. D'oh!) Again, this may or may not be overkill for your need, but I thought it was a fun hack. Enjoy!

Comment: Now that I look at this code again, I wish you could write `observable.propToWatch.observe(function () { ... })`. Oh well. Maybe I can tinker with it some more in the future.

Answer (score -1):

if your predicate become true when a variable change, here is another solution:

say we want to log 'Big brother is watching you' when value of object a become 2.

```
function observable (value, condition, callback){
    this.value = value;
    this.condition = condition;
    this.callback = callback;
}

observable.prototype = {
    get value () {
        return this._value;
    },
    set value (value) {
        this._value = value;
        if (this.condition && this.callback && this.condition (value)) {
            this.callback (value);
        }
    }
};

condition = function (value) {
    console.log ('condition', value);
    return value === 2;
}

callback = function (value) {
    console.info ('Big Brother is watching you!');
}

var a = new observable (0, condition, callback);

console.log ('set value to 1');
a.value = 1;
console.log ('set value to 2');
a.value = 2;
console.log ('set value to 3');
a.value = 3;
```

you can try this exemple in firefox

Comment: what is get and set? is this standard javascript?

Comment: Getters and setters will not work in all javascript implementations.

Comment: this won't work less you have firebug installed and opened. (because you are using console)

Comment: well, I don't know if it is standart javascript, I just found that (never really use it) it does not work with internet explorer, according to http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/ it's working in firefox, safari and opera