# Patterns or techniques for ensuring script availability?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, design-patterns

As a project I have been working on has grown, so has the frequency of situations where all scripts on a page are not available when other code tries to access them. Though this happens most often after code is updated (e.g. not cached) I've had it come up more and more in testing, when it never used to happen.

I've addressed this, partially, by using a function to wait for a module to become available (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316666/watch-for-a-property-creation-event)) and this addresses the concern, mostly, but I'm not totally thrilled with the implementation, and am looking for a more industrial strength pattern to deal with this. These are possible solutions I've come up with:

1) **Load scripts on demand** with something like [ensure](http://ensure.codeplex.com/) - not ideal. Requires actual script name dependency information to be included in each script, not just module/object name, to do this. Still have to take some action before using a resource to ensure it's available.

2) **Manage script loading order**. If this would even work (e.g. I don't think that simply putting script A before script B guarantees it will be available since they can be loaded concurrently), it would be a pain, since you don't know a dependency until you've loaded the thing that depends on it. Would require a lot of work to set up on a site that has lots of pages that use different resources (and I have no intention of loading everything used everywhere on the site on every page).

3) **Wait for everything** to be loaded on a given page before allowing user interaction. Far from ideal for obvious reasons. Still doesn't address dependencies that happen in initialization code.

4) **Expand upon my current solution.** Currently works like (this is pseudocode, but the basic logic process):

```
// Depends on Module2
Module1 = (function () {
   self = {};
   // function requires dependency
   // waitFor waits until global named 'dependency' is available then calls callback
   self.initialized=false; 
   self.init = function() {
       waitFor('Module2', function() {
           self.intialized=true;
       });
   }
  // waitForInitialization sets a callback when self.initialized=true
   self.func = self.waitForInitialization(func() {
           Module2.doStuff();
       });
   }
   //UI-initiated function requires dependency
   self.uiFunc = function() {
       if (!self.initialized) {
          showPleaseWaitDialog();
          self.waitForInitialization(function() {
              dismissPleaseWaitDialog();
              self.uiFuncImpl);
       } else {
          self.uiFuncImpl();
       }
   }
   self.uiFuncImpl= function() { 
       Module2.doStuff();
   }
} ());
```

I can think of ways to create a prototype that would deal with the dependency issue more transparently than my code above, and fully intend to do that if I have to, but is this truly the best solution? What do others do? What are considered best practices?

Comment: Whats wrong with progressive enhancement and calling your javascript functions/objects on document.ready?

Comment: document.ready does not guarantee includes are loaded, just the DOM.

Comment: @Jamietre you will find that the jQuery document.ready does garantuee that javascript includes from the head are loaded.

Comment: I'm using jQuery, and it's the first include, and I can easily reproduce this. What could I be doing wrong? There are easily 20 includes on some pages, is there any possible reason why browser-specific behavior could cause this to not work? All the includes are in head, too. Some are dynamic (e.g. resource loaders).

Comment: In theory you should be able to define your modules/classes and use `$(document).ready(function() { module1.init(); module2.init(); ... });` to deal with this. Maybe look at say head.js or require.js.

Comment: Oh - script order, probably. Includes that run themselves (module code)  - how would I ever be able to ensure that they run in the right order? Won't the first block of document.ready code run before a self-initializing module that was included later?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { module1.init(); module2.init(); ... });` .. if `module1` is included, and initialized in `document.ready`, then I would expect it to be run after document.ready code in a previous module or in the page. If it's not intialized in document.ready, but just in the window, it's own dependencies are not guaranteed to be available. I think that would only work if there was just one level of dependecy, but some includes depend on other includes.

Comment: jamietre is correct about document.ready assuming his js is loaded in the body of the document, if it is loaded in the head document.ready guarantees it to be there but that's a side effect of the way browsers handle scripts in the head tag.

Comment: I'm still confused about the document.ready/scripts thing. I can assure you that my document.ready code is firing *before* an include script has *run*. Maybe it's been loaded, but a module created with the pattern above (in an include, NOT in document.ready) may not have finished creating itself yet, and may not exist when the code in the body document.ready runs. That is the very nature of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) Script Load Order - scripts will always be executed in the order they are placed in the DOM, so while they might load concurrently they will execute in an orderly fashion (faced this same problem on a large project I worked on).

?) If script load order is not an ideal solution for you, you could look into the [Promise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbuckton/archive/2010/01/29/promises-and-futures-in-javascript.aspx)  model.

??) If Promises and Load Order won't work for you, you could listen for a namespaced event that each module could fire when it's initialized, that way if the object exists it can be used and if not its initialization could be listened for.

Comment: Good to know load order is respected. It's difficult, because I would have to add dependency information to the resource management process I'm using and have it deal with it. Things tend to come out exactly backwards now (as modules are added by the module that needs a dependency). But since it actually will work - this is probably the best solution. I'm basically using promises now (except rather than specifically requesting a resource be loaded, I wait for it to appear). Hadn't considered the event model, sounds interesting and better than my current way.

Comment: I noticed that after I posted about Promises, they seem to be getting popular very quickly. The event model isn't ideal in my opinion, but it's effective and lets your modules remain ignorant of things it doesn't need to know. All each object has to know is what its dependency is.

Comment: It works, I'm just not happy about having to make every method do something else when it has a dependency. As I alluded to at the end of the original question, I think something could me developed to encapsulate this somehow, but sounds like work. For my situation, getting the code to arrange scripts bottom-first will probably be easier, if that will actually solve the problem.

Comment: I use a base object that has extension methods, other objects add themselves to the base class to register their namespace, and the base object adds the necessary code based on those namespaces to trigger events, and grabs dependency data from the objects to handle listeners. It also allows me to use a more classical style of inheritance than basic js allows.

Comment: Basically the js equivalent of having class ClassName extends OtherClass, where OtherClass extends BaseClass.

Comment: Interesting, I would love to see an example of how you have coded this.

Comment: Space is limited here for the code so I'll see if I can't find a place to post the relevant stuff on a front facing server.