# Can Javascript do dynamic properties like Swift's @dynamicMemberLookup?

Tags: javascript

In Swift we have `@dynamicMemberlookup` which lets us dynamically reference a property without having to first define it. Great for situations where keys names on things like maps are not known in advance. For example I can do something like this:

```swift
object.abc = 5
object.abc // -> 5
```

And the compiler will call a pre-defined function:

```swift
subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> Int {
    get { return someMap[member] }
    set { someMap[member] = newValue
}
```

Effectively it's syntactical sugar. But what I'm doing at the moment is calling some user supplied Javascript from my Swift app and as part of that call I'm passing an object to the javascript which can be used to get and retrieve values.

At the moment I've defined `function get(key) {...}` and function `set(key, value) {...}` functions on the object I'm passing. This allows:

```js
object.set("abc", 5);
object.get("abc"); // -> 5
```

But I'd really like the javascript to be able to do a dynamic property without knowing the name of it in advance. ie:

```js
object.abc = 5;
object.abc; // -> 5
```

I've looked around but I can't see if this is possible in Javascript. Is it?

## Edit

ultimately the object I pass to the javascript is a Swift object and the `get` and `set` functions I defined in the javascript are actually routing to the backing Swift object in a dynamic manner. That means that when I call the javascript I don't have to pass every single value currently stored. Which could be a large amount.

Comment: Did you try running it? Yes, `object.abc = 5; object.abc; // -> 5` will work

Comment: It will crate a property dynamically, but I need to route the value to an internal map. How do I do that? Plus I don't want to actually create a new property as such.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I follow you but is this what you want ?

```js
let propName = 'abc' ;
object[propName] = 5 
console.log(object[propName]) ;
```

you can change the property name to anything you want and it will just create, set and retrieve that property

Comment: Sort of, but I need to advise a backing Swift object that it has occurred. So I need a function to be called when the property is created. Like a `didSet`.

Comment: something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316666/watch-for-a-property-creation-event