# javascript WAIT for something to be true

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, wait

i create in a javascript function a prototype window. in the window i load a site where the user has to select something. i want the javascript function to wait until the user selected something and then return the value of the what the user selected.

```
function showTargetDirectoryChooser(){
  var win = new Window( 'dirchooser_' + new Date().getTime() , {className: 'alphacube', width: 320, height: 470, url: '/directories/choose', maximizable: false});
  win.showCenter();
  win.setDestroyOnClose();

  // WAIT_UNTIL( win.content.contentWindow.Directory != null )

  return win.content.contentWindow.Directory
}
```

i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296583/javascript-wait-for-something-to-be-true-then-run-action) something i could maybe use - but i dont understand how to...

Comment: If you're using the `Prototype` library, you can use [periodicalExecuter](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/periodicalExecuter) utility to poll the status of `win.content.contentWindow.Directory` every, say, 5 seconds.

Comment: that does not really fit my problem, i want the user to use a button to signalize that he is finish selecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an asynchronous process; it’s probably better to handle this with a callback.

For example, couldn’t you use a [closeCallback](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/documentation.html#setCloseCallback)?

```
function showTargetDirectoryChooser(done){
  var win = new Window( 'dirchooser_' + new Date().getTime() , {className: 'alphacube', width: 320, height: 470, url: '/directories/choose', maximizable: false});
  win.showCenter();
  win.setDestroyOnClose();

  // This will ensure 
  win.setCloseCallback(function () {
      done(win.content.contentWindow.Directory);
      return true; // or return false if you don't want the window to be closed
  });

  return true;
}
```

With this, you would change

```
var chosenDir = showTargetDirectoryChooser();
// do something with chosen directory
```

into

```
var chosenDir;
showTargetDirectoryChooser(function (directory) {
    chosenDir = directory;
    // do something with the chosen directory
});
```

Comment: how do i make a button in the window closing the window?

Comment: @klump: `<button onclick="this.close()">OK</button>`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'close'` doesnt work. as i see it i have to call `win.close();` but i dont have the variable `win` in the window...

Comment: @klump: Ah, silly me!  I meant `<button onclick="window.close()">OK</button>`... `win` is the variable defined in your function, but within the window itself, it is accessible by the `window` variable.

Comment: mhhh. now the error message disappeared, but the window does not close. i have still to click on the cross...

Comment: how do you mean? like a prototype window with alphacube theme (maximizing disabled)...

Comment: Hmmm... I was confusing Prototype windows with actual windows.  You need something like `Dialog.okCallback()` instead of `window.close()` — if that works on a 'plain' window.  Is there no event in your Directory Chooser that could be observed?

Comment: a click on a button? the user can select an item and then he has to click on the button...

Comment: but how do i set a callback to that button? `win.content.contentWindow.document.$('my_button').observe( 'click' , function(){...` does not work: --> `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLDocument] has no method '$'` :/

Comment: ok, i fixed it with `<button onclick="top.Windows.getFocusedWindow().close()>OK</button>` - works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an event handler.  When `Directory` is set via click or perhaps a change event, if that is fired, attach a handler which takes that event and passes it back to a function in your main window.  This will require making your code asynchronous - so that you have a caller that calls `showTargetDirectoryChooser()` and a callback that takes the result of the directory as separate functions.  It shouldn't be too complicated to re-architect your code there and break it up to the caller and the callback, though.

You can also use setTimeout and poll the contents of `win.content.contentWindow.Directory` like so:

```
function showTargetDirectoryChooser(){
  var win = new Window( 'dirchooser_' + new Date().getTime() , {className: 'alphacube', width: 320, height: 470, url: '/directories/choose', maximizable: false});
  win.showCenter();
  win.setDestroyOnClose();

  setTimeout("pollDirectory()", 500); // poll in a half second
}

function pollDirectory() {
  if(win.content.contentWindow.Directory != null) {
    callback(win.content.contentWindow.Directory); // you will need an asynch callback
  } else {
    setTimeout("pollDirectory()", 500); // poll in a half second
  }

}
```

Doing it this way also requires that your code be asynchronous.

Another option is to look into jquery [wait](http://docs.jquery.com/Cookbook/wait), but that is a timeout as opposed to waiting on a condition.  Or there is a set of [reactive extensions to JS](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2010/02/16/introduction-to-the-reactive-extensions-to-javascript/), but that looks to be overkill for what you are doing.  The concept of an observable may be something you want to look into, though.

Comment: mhh i figured out for me that i need to do it with a timeout. i hoped that i could skip that but it does not seem so. i will try your answer.

Comment: @klump - I'd actually suggest doing an event (not sure how your chooser is structured, so I don't know what events it already fired or if you'd have to write a custom one) and callback as opposed to a timeout, but since I could code up a timeout I did.  If I had code for your chooser I would've written up an event handler instead.  It's cleaner.