# Passing a Javascript function as an argument in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using a Javascript function `do_when` to keep evaluating another function and perform an action once it returns true.  I found the function here: [javascript, wait for something to be true then run action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296583/javascript-wait-for-something-to-be-true-then-run-action)

Here is the `do_when` function:

```
function do_when(predicate, action, timeout_step) {
    if (predicate()) {
        action();
    } else {
        setTimeout(do_when, timeout_step, predicate, action, timeout_step);
    }
}
```

I am using it to call a jQuery function:

```
do_when(function() {return tabledrawn;},
    function() {$("#mytable tbody tr td").first().click();}, 
    100);
```

Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE9 (and earlier) fails.  Specifically, I get an "Object Expected" error when `do_when` is called from the `setTimeout` function.

When I do a debug, the predicate and action arguments correctly show up as function objects when `do_when` is initially called, but when it is called again from the `setTimeout` function they both show up as undefined.  It appears I am not supplying the arguments to `setTimeout` the way IE wants to see them.  Is there a proper way in IE to pass a function object and its parameters as arguments?

EDIT:
Per SLaks suggestions I changed `do_when` to the following:

```
function do_when(predicate, action, timeout_step) {
    if (predicate()) {
        action();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
                       do_when(predicate, action, timeout_step);
                   }, 
                   timeout_step);
    }
}
```

Which fixes my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing additional arguments to `setTimeout`, and you're expecting them to be passed to your function.

That's a non-standard Mozilla-only feature.

Instead, you need to pass an anonymous function to `setTimeout`, and call your function with whatever arguments you want inside of it.

Comment: Pour scorn and hatred on all non–standard behaviour!! Mozilla should lift its  game! Hang on, Mozilla? Sorry, mistook it for IE. In that case, non–standard stuff is fine…

Comment: This reminds me of the time I got bitten by the "lateness" parameter that was conveniently passed through my `$.proxy()` and caused some hair pulling =/